# makedirs() in loop creates invisible directory/folder?

Tags: python, macos, directory, operating-system

I am trying to mass produce folders that would be numbered `0,1,2...`

I use `os.makedirs()` in Python to do so.  It works if I am just creating a single folder, but when I use a `for` loop for mass production something weird happens.

When I open Finder (file browser in Mac), I don't see the folder there. Yet when I type in the folder's path in Mac's Go box (<kbd>cmd-shift-G</kbd>), then it magically appears, which means that the folder actually exists but was invisible for some reason.

Does anyone know why the folders are invisible?

```
import os
for i in range(3):
    os.makedirs('/Users/Olivia/code/'+str(i))
```

Comment: What if you refresh the directory?

Comment: On the Finder icon in your Taskbar, hold down the Option (^) + Control key, then click on **Relaunch**.  See if that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

I apologise if I'm interpreting the question wrong, but if you are saying that the folders cannot be seen on the desktop, I found that the folders are saved in your home (`'/Users/Olivia'` in your case) folder, so if you want to save the folders in your desktop, then you can do:

```py
import os
for i in range(3):
    os.makedirs("/Users/Olivia/Desktop/code/"+str(i))
```